# NodeJS app works locally but not when deployed on firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am trying to deploy a nodeJS app on firebase using this tutorial "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8&t=437s", I followed exactly what was told and the app worked as intended locally using "firebase serve" but when I deployed it, POST and GET request stopped working i.e. client side code is unable to reach server side.
for example, on loading **"appURL/temp"** I'm getting **"Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource"** error.

**What I'm actually trying to do :** to send JSON data from Client to server, process the data and return some result as response 
**What currently app does:** takes input, sends it to the server on click and receive it back as response to the POST request

on **Client Side (public/index.html)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/7.14.6/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <h1>Home</h1>
    <input type="text" id="ip">
    <button onclick="send()">send</button>
    <div id="text"></div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      let textDiv = document.getElementById("text")
      function send(){
        let ip = document.getElementById("ip").value;

        axios.post('/home',ip)
        .then( resp => {
          textDiv.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(resp.data);
        })
      }


    </script>
  </body>
```

on **Server Side (functions/index.js**

```
const func = require('./add'); //this is just to wrap the string with brackets
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const multer  = require('multer'); 
const upload = multer();
const app = express();

app.get('/temp', (req, resp) => {
    resp.send("GET Works");
    console.log("GET");
})


app.post('/home', upload.single("data"), (req, res) => {
    console.log(func.add(JSON.stringify(req.body)))
    res.send(func.add(JSON.stringify(req.body)))
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

**firebase.json**

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites":[{
      "source": "**",
      "function": "app"
    }],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Directory Structure**
[image]

**Versions**
**node** : 13.6.0
**express** : 6.13.4
**mutler** : 6.13.4

Comment: did you get build before serving to app?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what you mean by getting build before serving to app. But my problem got solved. The reason it was happening was because the functions never got deployed which I found out about by checking function source in Firebase console. After deploying second time it worked. Still, I appreciate your quick response.

Comment: I thought you may forget to take new build, serve earlier build.I mean node app build.